# Selenium 2 (WebDriver) + Java + Maven + Eclipse Hello World Program issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver

Java "Hello World" project convert to Maven Project and it stopped working with error

> "Error: Could not find or load main class...."

Hi All,

I did lot of search in google but couldn't find any Hello World program for `Selenium 2 ( WebDriver )+ Java + Maven + Eclipse` setup instructions

I'm having below setup

> 1. Eclipse with Maven plugin
> 2. Created a Java project "Hello World" and it worked fine when ran as "Java Application"
> 3. Then converted this to Marven Project.
> 4. Tried to run whole project but it didn't run
> 5. Tried to run Hello World file and it's consistently failed with error "Error: Could not find or load main class...."

Questions:

> 1. How to setup and run basis selenium 2 program with maven inside Eclipse
> 2. Why java stopped working after converting to Maven project.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vikram

Comment: Selenium Vicky_pedia ( https://wordpress.com/post/vikramviknowledgesharing.wordpress.com/182 )

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Cannot reproduce.

Here's how I did it (Eclipse 4.3 Kepler, Oracle JDK 7u25):

1. I made a new `Hello World` Java project (right click in the Package Explorer -> `New` -> `Java project`):

   [image: New Java project]
2. I named it `Hello World` and clicked <kbd>Finish</kbd>. I created a new package in the `src` folder named `hello` and a new class `HelloWorld` in it:

   [image: New package and class created]
3. I implemented the `HelloWorld` class and ran it (<kbd>F11</kbd>):

   [image: Hello World impl]

   [image: Hello world impl result]
4. I converted the project to a Maven Project (right click on the project -> `Configure` -> `Convert to Maven Project`), clicked <kbd>Finish</kbd>

   [image: Convert to Maven Project]
5. I fixed the errors Maven was throwing at me.

   It said *"Project build error: 'artifactId' with value 'Hello World' does not match a valid id pattern."*, so I figured `Hello World` might be invalid because of the space. I was right. Removing the space from `Artifact Id` and `Group Id` fixed the build.

   Before:

   [image: Before fixing Maven project]

   After (don't forget to save the file via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>):

   [image: After fixing Maven project]
6. Right now, everything worked as intended. The `HelloWorld` class, when ran, still output the same thing as before. The project now had a slightly different folder structure (new `bin` and `target` folders, new `pom.xml` file):

   [image: Maven Project file structure]
7. I added Selenium dependancy. Open `pom.xml`, click the `Dependencies` tab, click <kbd>Add...</kbd>, find `Selenium-java`, specify version `2.33.0`.

   [image: Add Selenium dependancy]

   After I clicked <kbd>OK</kbd> and saved the POM file, I had to wait for Maven to download all the Selenium goodies and dependencies, that took a while (observe the Progress toolbar in Eclipse doing something).

   The only thing that changed was that the project structure had a new `Maven Dependencies` item containing Selenium and all of its depenedencies.

   [image: Maven Dependencies]
8. I was ready to roll with Selenium:

   [image: Selenium Hello World]

   When run, this opens Firefox, goes to Google and finishes.

Comment: Try `driver.close()` to see if driver is able to close one tab

Comment: @IowA Are you sure you posted your comment to the right answer? Because I have no idea what your comment has to do with anything in here. 1) We have no problem with closing anything. 2) WebDriver doesn't support tabs, only windows, so technically `close()` closes a window. Can you elaborate on what you meant?

Comment: Hi Slanec, Thanks for detailed answer. I re-tried same steps as you had mentioned but still no luck.  Getting below error in pom.xml "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)" . Is this error in pom.xml not allowing to run simple java program ? And how to fix this pom.xml issue.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm on my cell phone, but when I'll be back at my PC, I'll post here my pom.xml, my maven and my m2e versions. In the meantime, I remember a similar issue that was solved by wrapping all your plugin stuff in the POM into a `<pluginManagement>` tag.

Comment: Please find below version from my Windows Vista ... Eclipse Standard/SDK Kepler Release , m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.xxxx . Some other post I saw comment saying there may be issue with Maven plugin version . Please share your versions screen shot.

Comment: How to run Maven project? By running pom.xml?

Comment: @RiponAlWasim By running the class that contains `public static void main(String... args)` method. For maven-specific options, you can also right-click the project and select Run As ... Maven something. That will enable you to execute the various Maven tasks - clean, install, etc. But to run your project, you can simply act as if there was no Maven.